# PMD issue to be fixed

Tags: java, pmd

```
for(Deductible **myDeductible**: myDeductibles){
    myReturnList.add(myOption); // Add options as many times as number of deductibles
    if(CoverageConstants.COVERAGE_CODE_VC.equalsIgnoreCase(aCoverage.getCoverageCd()) &&
            !CoverageConstants.OPTION_CODE_ONE.equals(myOption.getOptionCd())){
        break;
    }
}
```

uppder code how to fix unused local variable myDeductible .please give suggestion.

Comment: You can either suppress the warning (`@SuppressWarnings`) or use the local variable, it's not an error unless you treat warnings as if they're errors.

Comment: i cant use...any code change u r finding??i cant even use supress warnings also

Comment: You could add a very low level logger for this variable, so that it would be printed in the log file unless you have low level configured in the log config file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `for(Deductible myDeductible: myDeductibles){` use old style loop:

```
for(int count = 0; count < myDeductibles.size(); count++) {
```

Comment: any other option???according to application standard...i have to use new loop format...

Comment: Either this or SuppressWarnings

Answer (score 0):

PMD lets you know that you're assigning but not using `myDeductible`, i.e. there is something fishy going on.

Looking at the snippet you provided, we can see several inputs (`myDeductibles`, `myOption` and `aCoverage`) and one output (`myReturnList`). Furthermore there is the loop that fills `myReturnList` with `myOption`s and a condition that breaks the loop.

A closer look at the condition tells us that within the loop the condition is either always `true` or always `false`, assuming the getters have no side effects and return always the same.

From this we can deduce that once the loop finishes `myReturnList` can have only one of exactly three states:

1. when `myDeductibles` is empty then `myReturnList` is empty
2. when `myDeductibles` is not empty and the condition is `true` then `myReturnList` contains exactly one `myOption` because the condition breaks the loop after adding the first `myOption`
3. when `myDeductibles` is not empty and the condition is `false` then `myReturnList` contains exactly as many `myOption`s as there are elements in `myDeductibles`

You might have noticed that none of the three outcomes above depend on the elements of `myDeductibles` themselves, only on the amount of the elements. That’s what PMD is trying to tell us.

Now that we know what the loop is really doing, we can fix the warning by implementing the three outcomes without using the elements of `myDeductibles`:

```
List<Option> myReturnList;

if (myDeductibles.isEmpty()) {
    myReturnList = Collections.emptyList();

} else if (CoverageConstants.COVERAGE_CODE_VC.equalsIgnoreCase(aCoverage.getCoverageCd())
           && !CoverageConstants.OPTION_CODE_ONE.equals(myOption.getOptionCd())) {
    myReturnList = Collections.singletonList(myOption);

} else {
    myReturnList = Collections.nCopies(myDeductibles.size(), myOption);
}
```